# Jquery simple if statement confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a confirmation alert to confirm a user action.

on click "ok", it should do the following code:

```
function disableSubmitButton() {
    jQuery("#submitButton").attr("disabled", "true");
    jQuery("#rent_space").submit();
}
```

on "cancel", the following.

```
if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed ?')) {
    return false;
}
```

However, the way my code is currently formated, the first block of code is executed regardless of which button is pressed.

I think this is pretty much just moving the code around, but I'm unsure how to correctly do it as my precedent attempts all failed. Any help appreciated. Thanks !

Full code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(onDocumentReady);
        function onDocumentReady() {

            jQuery("#submitButton").click(disableSubmitButton);

            jQuery('#submitButton').click(function() {
                if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed ?')) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }
        function disableSubmitButton() {
            jQuery("#submitButton").attr("disabled", "true");
            jQuery("#rent_space").submit();
        }
</script>
```

Comment: what is #submitButton? Can you show the markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
//jQuery("#submitButton").click(disableSubmitButton);

jQuery('#submitButton').click(function() {
if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed ?')) {
    return false;
}
else
{
    disableSubmitButton();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to disable the submit button? Returning false on the other click should be enough.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(onDocumentReady);
        function onDocumentReady() {

            jQuery('#submitButton').click(function() {
                if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed ?')) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }

</script>
```

However I would instead bind to the submit event:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(onDocumentReady);
        function onDocumentReady() {

            jQuery('#rent_space').submit(function() {
                if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed ?')) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }

</script>
```

Comment: I think he's disabling it only when the form is submitted. The function name doesn't reflect only what the function does, so it's a little confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one event listener. The condition can be handled in the listener body.

```
jQuery("#submitButton").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(confirm("...")) {
    jQuery("#submitButton").attr("disabled", "true");
    jQuery("#rent_space").submit();
  }
});
```

NB. you should use `e.preventDefault()` instead of `return false` to prevent the default behaviour of an event.

Answer (score 1):

Hari's answer is correct. I prefer the (slightly) more idiomatic:

```
jQuery("#submitButton").click(function() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed?")) {
        disableSubmitButton();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT EDIT** I got it to work thanks to your suggestions. Thank you. :)

Heres the code that worked.

```
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(onDocumentReady);
            function onDocumentReady() {

                jQuery('#submitButton').click(function() {
                    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed ?')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else{
                        jQuery("#submitButton").click(disableSubmitButton);
                    }
                });

            }
            function disableSubmitButton() {
                jQuery("#submitButton").attr("disabled", "true");
                jQuery("#rent_space").submit();
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: don't do this: `jQuery("#submitButton").click(disableSubmitButton);`. That is attaching ANOTHER click event, and not invoking it. You already have a click event for that button. I'm surprised that even works - the form isn't getting submitted, is it?

Comment: Oops, youre right. Bad copy pasta, this line is actually                     else {
                        disableSubmitButton();
                    } in my code :)

Comment: you kind of accepted the answer that you didn't choose to implement, but that's ok :)